# react-native-signature-canvas not working properly in expo IOS

Tags: react-native, expo

react-native-signature-canvas is not working properly in Expo, it throws an error "Unable to open URL".

I am using package of react-native-signature-canvas signature using env Expo.
What is going on here? I just simply copy and paste this code from [React Native Signature Component based Canvas for Android && IOS && expo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-signature-canvas).

I used the same code example provided on above page.

Error Message:

```
RemoteConsole.js:80 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Unable to open URL: ReactABI32_0_0-js-navigation://postMessage?data%253Aimage%252Fpng%253Bbase64%252CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAuQAAAVWCAYAAAD ... YII%253D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error, this error throws because of remote debugger is on after i stop remote debugging it works fine.